# Error 401 on writing to Skygear DB

Tags: android, skygear

do i need to do something else before writing into db?
receiving error 401

> E/Volley: [16286] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response
> code 401 for https://MASKED.skygeario.com/record/save
>
> I/Skygear Record Save:
> Fail to save: io.skygear.skygear.Error: write is not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skygear required user auth before writing to DB.
(not mentioned in doc)

After sign-in. It is OK.

Answer (score 0):

The record saving feature requires a current user to complete.
So you need to create a user and it will be fine to save the records.

You can check it out on how to signup a user here: https://docs.skygear.io/guides/auth/basics/android/